# SSH доступ из-под Windows

Tags: windows, ssh

Помогите решить проблему-
всегда сидел из-под unix систем, и зайти на рабочий комп не сoставляло труда:

```
ssh user@xxx.yyy.ru -p 65536
```

Как это реализовать из-под винды? Какой SSH-клиент использовать? Какой самый простой в настройке?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Лично я использую [PuTTY](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY)

достаточно прост в настройке и использовании

Answer (score 0):

Очень удобен в использовании [Bitwise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier)

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows 10 рекомендую использовать ssh-клиент из пакета [Git For Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), он дружит с UTF-8 в отличие от встроенного OpenSSH клиента.

Встроенный [имеет глюки с отображением UTF-8](https://b.tinyops.ru/fix-console-glitches-windows-10/), что выражается в кривом отображении кирилицы и мигании псевдографики (например, Midnight Commander).

После установки Git for Windows (включая все компоненты инсталлятора) нужно добавить путь до `%путь установки%/usr/bin` в переменную `PATH`.

Answer (score -3):

Если на сетевой компьютер, то помоему **net use ...**. Для получения подробностей, в командной строке наберите **net use /?**

Синтаксис данной команды:

```
NET USE
[имя_устройства | *] [\\имя_компьютера\имя_ресурса[\том] [пароль | *]]
        [/USER:[имя_домена\]имя_пользователя]
        [/USER:[имя_домена_с_точками\]имя_пользователя]
        [/USER:[имя_пользователя@имя_домена_с_точками]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {имя_устройства | *} [пароль | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```